# Array of pointers (to structs)

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to do something like this

```
typedef struct _thingy_t
{
    int num;
} thingy_t;

void go(int idk)
{
    // normally I could just do
    thingy_t* ary[idk];
    // but I need the array to be global    
}
```

I need an array of pointers to structs of size `idk`

Is using a 'double pointer' declared outside of the function the best way to go about this?
And what about malloc'ing space for the structs?

Comment: Where do you see "double pointer"? You'd better allocate memory: `thingy_t *array = calloc(idk, sizeof(thingy_t));`.

Comment: @Eddy_Em but the array would be specific to the function then, right? I need it to be global.

Comment: @Eddy_Em He nees an array of pointers..

Comment: @Wisatbff, I don't think so. I think he just don't know what exactly he wants. It will be global if you will define a global pointer to this structure. Allocating memory for it will "create" a global array.

Comment: There's another way: you can return pointer to you array from function. So there's at least 2 ways: 1) `thingy_t *array; ... void go(int idk){... array = calloc(idk, sizeof(thingy_t)); ...};` and 2) `thingy_t *go(int idk){... thingy_t *array = calloc(idk, sizeof(thingy_t)); ... return array;};` and somewhere else: `thingy_t *ar = go(size);`

Comment: @Eddy_Em so, outside of the function can I do `thingy_t **foo;` and in the function after doing `thingy_t *array = calloc(idk, sizeof(thingy_t));` then do `foo = array` ?

Comment: @Eddy_Em yes, I think that would work, but unfortunately my 'go' function needs to return something else

Comment: You can't return a pointer to a VLA from a function; the VLA goes out of scope.  If you want a variable-length array at global scope, or if you want to return a pointer from the function, you'll need to use dynamic memory allocation.  If a fixed size array is adequate, you can avoid dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: No, you don't need to use pointers to pointers to make simple array! If your function should return other, just make as I wrote in 1)

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, if array is small enough, he can use his construction with simple `static`, but anyway he would need a global pointer to assign.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare as global and then allocate memory inside function.

if you want to allocate memory for array.

```
void go(int);  

thingy_t *data=NULL; 
main()
{

   //read idk value.
   go(idk);

}
void go(int idk)
{
        data = malloc(idk * sizeof(thingy_t) );
       // when you allocate memory with the help of malloc , That will have scope even after finishing the function.

}
```

---

if you want to allocate memory for array of pointers.

```
thingy_t **data=NULL;

int main()
{
    int i,idk=10;
    go(idk);

    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
       {
       data[i]->num=i;
       printf("%d ",data[i]->num );
       }

return 0;
}

void go(int idk)
{
   int i=0;
   data=malloc(idk *sizeof( thingy_t * ));
   for ( i = 0; i<idk ; i++) {
      data[i]=malloc(sizeof( thingy_t));
   }
}
```

---

Don't forgot to `free()` the memory which is allocated with malloc.

Comment: > `thingy_t **data=NULL;`  ?? You sure?

Comment: `thingy_t **data = NULL;` was correct, he wants an array of pointers to `thingy_t`, not an array of `thingy_t`. It was `sizeof(thingy_t)` which was wrong, should have been `sizeof(thingy_t*)`, or even better, `sizeof(*data)`.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Yes, You are correct, OP wants array of pointers. modified my answer.

Comment: Do yourself a big favor and modify the name to distinguish that it is global, e.g "g_data", otherwise the OP will be posting a question within 2 days because his pointer goes missing and/or changes to it don't take hold :)